# Get memory map of a process in Windows?

Tags: windows, dictionary, memory

i actually need Opened memory addresses of process for example 
0x02000000 > Doesnt exist. 
0x00450000 > Exist.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366907(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: What are you going to do with that information? It doesn't immediately appear to be useful for anything.

Comment: @HansPassant thank you, do you have any example codes?
IInspectable Im making a memory view program :)